# Create SharePoint site group & assign to subsite in SharePoint online using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How to create SharePoint site group using PowerShell & assign it to subsite in SharePoint online?

Comment: Hi @Raja, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :) also check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/asking to know How to ask clear questions!